# Did Yosef's children inherit any of the riches that Yosef accumulated as a Vizier of Egypt?

Tags: parsha-torah-portion, vayigash

Also, the money that Yosef accumulated from all the people when they bought food, as it says in Beraishis 47:14. Did he get any part of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Ramban (Nachmanides) [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.47.14?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en):

> "he brought all money into Pharaoh’s house and did not accumulate for
> himself treasures of money and secret hiding places for wealth in the
> land of Egypt, or send it to the land of Canaan. Instead, he gave all
> money to the king who trusted him and purchased the land for him, and
> even the bodies of the Egyptians".

And

Rabbeinu Bahya [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.47.14?lang=bi&with=Rabbeinu%20Bahya&lang2=en):

> All the acquisitions Yosef made from the people he channeled to Pharaoh. He did not pocket any of it for himself. Although he took from the people their most precious possessions he remained popular with them. This was clearly something that G-d had arranged.

And

The Tur HaAroch [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.47.14?lang=bi&with=Tur%20HaAroch&lang2=en)

> in that whatever he collected he handed over to Pharaoh’s treasury. He did not amass a private fortune of his own.

I hope this will answer your question

Comment: I thought Korah found one9f his secret treasures, Joseph’s I mean. So I guess it means it was really Pharaohs.

Comment: Indeed, the Gemara (Sanhedrin 110a) states that Yosef concealed three buried treasures in Egypt - שָׁלֹשׁ מַטְמוֹנִיּוֹת הִטְמִין יוֹסֵף בְּמִצְרַיִם (see also: Pesachim 119a, Rabbi Ḥama bar Ḥanina said: Joseph hid three treasures in Egypt. One of them was revealed to Korah). In Sanhedrin, the treasures are linked to what Yosef accumulated from the sale of grain during the years of famine. I recommend reading the commentary of the Ben Yehoyada on Sanhedrin 110a:12. Anyone know how this can be solved with the commentary of Ramban in mind, that there was no secret hiding in Egypt? See first note